# Div with fixed position still scrolls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have a fixed positioned div (#stoerer), but it still scrolls (but just optically). Look at this: [this gif explane what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A5CV.gif)

This is my code:

```
<div id="stoerer">
   <button class="closed"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
   <h1>OSTERSPECIAL!</h1>
   <h2>EINMALIGE ANGEBOT ZU OSTERN</h2>
   <a href="<?= BASEURL ?>angebote"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Erfahre mehr</a>
</div>

#stoerer {
    //display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 15%;
    @include box_shadow(4);
    width: 350px;
    background: $mvBlue;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: try overflow:initial

Comment: If you can provide [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of it, we can help you better.

Comment: your code in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/24th3sb9/

Comment: I had the same issue once. Turns out i had the `will-change` css property set on a main wrapper element for an off-canvas navigation (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/will-change). Inside this wrapper was my fixed element. Everything worked fine after removing `will-change`. Have you done anything similar to this?

Comment: Is `#stoerer` nested inside another non-fixed element?

Comment: - overflow:initial is not working,

Comment: it's a whole website i can't provide a jsfiddle of it.

Comment: i don't have a will-change in my whole css.

Comment: yes #stoerer is in a non-fixed element.

Comment: I had this issue just moments ago. For me, it was removing `transform: translateZ(0)` from the parent container that did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

i found the reason, it was a parent div which has a `-webkit-perspective: 1000;` css property, i just removed it. :) anyway thanks for the commments.

Comment: Look I said, the issue is in some other part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your div. `position:fixed` is doing its work. The problem lies elsewhere, you need to check your complete code. Else, see this snippet, `position:fixed` always stays same position on screen, no matter what. The issue is in some other part of your code.

```css
#stoerer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 15%;
    width: 350px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div id="stoerer">
   <button class="closed">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>
   <h1>OSTERSPECIAL!</h1>
   <h2>EINMALIGE ANGEBOT ZU OSTERN</h2>
   <a href="<?= BASEURL ?>angebote"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Erfahre mehr</a>
</div>
```